# Can i configure "New", "Sale" and "IN STOCK" from admin panel ?

Tags: admin

So.. can i configure these options somewhere in admin panel ? perhaps theme settings.. or ?

[image]

Comment: No, Magento doesn't give this functionality. Do you want to add just labels?

Comment: Nope, i want to change that label. :)

Comment: are you using magento 1 or 2?

Comment: Magento 1.9.3.7 :)

Comment: Need more informations

Answer (score 1):

You can use below link to download Product label extension

**Link1:-**https://www.magestore.com/magento-product-labels-extension.html#prettyPhoto

**Link2:-**https://github.com/WaPoNe/module-stickers